# Values Don't Get Modified in Vector of List of Class

Tags: c++, list, class, vector, stl

I am a beginner in using C++ STL and have just recently started working on Vectors. 
I am trying to build a data structure of type- vector of list of class objects.

I find that whenever I try to make changes in my class object variable, the changes get written as wanted. However, the same class variables return previous values if I read them back.

Here is the simplified version of my code that first initializes all the boolean variable values to '0'.

Then, I negate all the boolean values and observe that variables get value '1' after inversion.

However, when I display my list again, I see them get back to '0'.

Here's the piece of code I have used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class edge{
private:
   bool _id;

public:
   void invert_id()
   {
      _id = !_id;
   }

   bool get_id()
   {
      return _id;
   }

   edge(bool id) //Constructor
   {
      _id = id;
   }
};

void display_list(vector<list<edge> > &adjList);
void negate_list(vector<list<edge> > &adjList);

int main() {

   vector<list<edge> > adjList(2);

   adjList[0].push_back(edge(false));
   adjList[0].push_back(edge(false));
   adjList[1].push_back(edge(false));
   adjList[1].push_back(edge(false));
   adjList[1].push_back(edge(false));

   cout<<endl <<"Original List-->" <<endl;
   display_list(adjList);

   cout<<endl <<"Inverted List-->" <<endl;
   negate_list(adjList);

   cout<<endl <<"List After Inversion-->" <<endl;
   display_list(adjList);
}
```

Here are the functions I have written that have the vectors passed by reference:

```
void display_list(vector<list<edge> > &adjList)
{
 int c=0;
 for (vector<list<edge> >::iterator i=adjList.begin(); i !=adjList.end(); ++i)
 {
    cout<<"AdjList["<< c<<"] IDs =";
    list<edge> li = *i;

    for(list<edge>::iterator iter = li.begin(); iter!= li.end(); ++iter)
    {
       cout<<"  "<<(*iter).get_id();
    }
    cout<<endl;
    c++;
 }
}

void negate_list(vector<list<edge> > &adjList)
{
int c=0;
   for (vector<list<edge> >::iterator i=adjList.begin(); i !=adjList.end(); ++i)
   {
      cout<<"AdjList["<< c<<"] IDs =";
      list<edge> li = *i;

      for(list<edge>::iterator iter = li.begin(); iter!= li.end(); ++iter)
      {
         (*iter).invert_id();
         cout<<"  "<<(*iter).get_id();
      }
      cout<<endl;
      c++;
   }
}
```

The Output I get is:

```
Original List-->
AdjList[0] IDs =  0  0
AdjList[1] IDs =  0  0  0

Inverted List-->
AdjList[0] IDs =  1  1
AdjList[1] IDs =  1  1  1

List After Inversion-->
AdjList[0] IDs =  0  0
AdjList[1] IDs =  0  0  0
```

As seen above, I am not able to understand why the values get reverted back to '0' even after updating them to '1'.

Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list<edge> li = *i;
```

This is a **deep copy** for the `std::list`. Any change you did on this `std::list` will not affect the original one.

This should solve your problem:

```
void negate_list(vector<list<edge> > &adjList){
   int c=0;
   for (auto i=adjList.begin(); i !=adjList.end(); ++i){
      cout<<"AdjList["<< c<<"] IDs =";
      for(auto iter = i->begin(); iter!= i->end(); ++iter){
         (*iter).invert_id();
         cout<<"  "<<(*iter).get_id();
      }
      cout<<endl;
      c++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this answers my question. I really appreciate your prompt response to this question. And yes, the solution you suggest did solve the problem by avoiding deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason your `negate_list` function takes its vector argument by reference, the `li` variable in the body of the function must be a reference.

`list<edge> li = *i;` is actually calling the copy constructor of the STL list type, and as [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/) states:

> [it] constructs a container **with a copy of each of the elements** in [the list], in the same order.

This is what Humam means by "deep copy". Once an `edge` is copied, any modifications are obviously performed on the copy. Referring to the list by reference, however, will allow us to access the original `edge` elements by reference and therefore modify them.

Comment: Thank you very much for a more elaborate response, Frangio. The link you have shared clarifies the concept for a beginner like me. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Make sure to akways read the documentation!